# Close sub Tab on Account Change from Workspace API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, workspaceapi

Hi I need some help on the situation as whenever someone change the Account then if subtab is open then it should close...

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This question is likely to be voted closed because it does not include enough detail or context to understand the problem. Please take our [Tour] and read [ask] and [On Topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Then, [edit] your question to add all of the context and details, including the *relevant* code or metadata, needed for someone else to understand what you're working on. Please make sure to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Still not clear as what is opened as Primary Tab and what is opened as a subtab and on change of which object which tab needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do some JavaScript development using the [Aura Framework's Workspace API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/specification). On apps that use the console navigation, the framework emits some events that you can handle. One of those is the ["tab closed" event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabClosed/documentation).

From the [Using Events with the Lightning Console JavaScript API
documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_events.htm):

> The Lightning framework uses event-driven programming, which allows you to create handlers to respond to interface events as they occur. The Lightning Console JavaScript API provides several events specific to Lightning console apps.

> You can use Lightning console events with the Workspace API and Utility Bar API to customize your users’ experience.

If you are not comfortable with development in general, or specifically with JavaScript, I suggest you find an experienced developer for this - or, even better: a certified consulting partner.